# Python pycord: AttributeError: 'ApplicationContext' object has no attribute 'selected_options'

Tags: python, discord, pycord

I have 2 commands: `test` and `send_arg`. During the execution of the `test` command, it becomes necessary to receive data from the `send_arg` command.

I'm waiting for the `send_arg` command to be called via `wait_for`, and I pass the context to `test` to get the argument passed to `send_arg`.

But when I try to get the `selected_options` property, I get an error.

```py
AttributeError: 'ApplicationContext' object has no attribute 'selected_options'
```

At the same time, **[looking at the documentation](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html#discord.ApplicationContext)**, I was convinced that such a property definitely exists.

[image]

[image]

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.commands import Option

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.slash_command()
async def send_arg(ctx, arg: Option(str, choices=['var1', 'var2', 'var3'], required=True)):
    pass

@bot.slash_command()
async def test(ctx):

    def check(context):
        return context.author == ctx.author

    app_cmd_ctx = await bot.wait_for('application_command', check=check)
    print(app_cmd_ctx.selected_options)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

py-cord version:

```py
pip install py-cord==2.0.0b1
```

Comment: What version of pycord are you on?

Comment: Could not reproduce this, can you [edit] your post to include the version of discord you are using?

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs, Added, thanks for the reminder, completely forgot about it

Comment: @denisnumb can you try updating to the latest version with `pip install git+https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord` and see if it persists?

Comment: ok, I try it, but I don't have git installed, please wait

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs thanks, it worked! everything worked after the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

`ApplicationContext.selected_options` does not exist in pycord versions before version 2.0 beta 5.
To fix your error, you can either update pycord to this version using `pip install git+https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord`.

If you need to use version 2.0 beta 1 or any other version prior to beta 5, you can replace `ApplicationContext.selected_options` with the following code:

### Code

```py
ApplicationContext.interaction.data.get("options", None)
```

### Reference

[Application Context](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html#applicationcontext)

[Commit where this property was added](https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord/commit/5a30d49ec06d97f09d2d1424f6dd33d34c310e45)