# Why does Slash Commands in Pycord not give response in discord?

Tags: python, discord.py, pycord

I am trying to make a discord bot that allows the user to play games with other users. I am using [pycord](https://pycord.dev/) with python version `3.10.8`.

Here is my code:-

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
import discord,os

global TOKEN,bot,main,games

TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")
bot = discord.Bot()
main = bot.create_group("nisticks","Nisticks Commands")
games = main.create_subgroup("games","Nisticks Games Commands")

@games.command(description="Tic Tac Toe")
async def ttt(ctx):
    await ctx.respond("gg")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.add_application_command(main)
    bot.run(TOKEN)
```

After running the slash command in discord:-

[image]

It shows this:-

[image]

And this error comes in python:-

```html
Ignoring exception in on_interaction
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 124, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(arg)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 1310, in _invoke
    await command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 372, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 292, in prepare
    if not await self.can_run(ctx):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 390, in can_run
    local_check = cog._get_overridden_method(cog.cog_check)
AttributeError: '_MissingSentinel' object has no attribute '_get_overridden_method'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\bot.py", line 1114, in invoke_application_command
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 375, in invoke
    await injected(ctx)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 132, in wrapped
    raise ApplicationCommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command raised an exception: AttributeError: '_MissingSentinel' object has no attribute '_get_overridden_method'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 377, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\bot.py", line 1167, in on_interaction
    await self.process_application_commands(interaction)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\bot.py", line 848, in process_application_commands
    await self.invoke_application_command(ctx)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\bot.py", line 1118, in invoke_application_command
    await ctx.command.dispatch_error(ctx, exc)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 418, in dispatch_error
    local = cog.__class__._get_overridden_method(cog.cog_command_error)
AttributeError: type object '_MissingSentinel' has no attribute '_get_overridden_method'
Ignoring exception in command nisticks games:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 124, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(arg)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 1310, in _invoke
    await command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 372, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 292, in prepare
    if not await self.can_run(ctx):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 390, in can_run
    local_check = cog._get_overridden_method(cog.cog_check)
AttributeError: '_MissingSentinel' object has no attribute '_get_overridden_method'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\bot.py", line 1114, in invoke_application_command
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 375, in invoke
    await injected(ctx)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 132, in wrapped
    raise ApplicationCommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command raised an exception: AttributeError: '_MissingSentinel' object has no attribute '_get_overridden_method'
```

This other [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71646846/python-pycord-attributeerror-applicationcontext-object-has-no-attribute-sel) related to this had answer that rold to run:-

```bash
pip install git+https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord
```

but it didn't make a difference. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It's because you *don't* respond.

```
@games.command(description="Tic Tac Toe")
async def ttt(ctx):
    print(await ctx.__dict__)
```

`print` prints to the Python console. It doesn't send anything back to Discord. You'll see it on the server side but not the client. You also can't `await` a dictionary; you have to `await` an *awaitable* object (such as a coroutine).

To respond to Discord, you use [`ctx.respond`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api.html#discord.ApplicationContext.respond). That function *does* produce a coroutine, so we await that function call. To print your object's dictionary to the Discord channel, use

```
await ctx.respond(str(ctx.__dict__))
```

Comment: I am so sry, i had this in this in the code `await ctx.respond("gg")` and it didnt work (gave the same error)  so i replaced it with the print statement @Silvio Mayolo

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may try using the following:

```
await ctx.response.send_message('a message you want')
```

I use this for responds in my bot.

Comment: This is discord.py, the post asks about Pycord